# Can algorithms of arbitrarily worse complexity be systematically created?

Tags: complexity-theory, algorithm-analysis, code-generation

We’ve all seen this:
[image: Hierarchy of time complexities]

Can we get worse?

Part 1: Can mathematical operations of increasing orders of growth be generated, with or without Knuth’s up-arrow notation?

Part 2: If they can, can algorithms of arbitrary complexities be systematically generated?

Part 3: If such algorithms can be generated, what about programs implementing those algorithms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course.  $2^{f(n)}$ is asymptotically larger than $f(n)$, so you can come up with an unending sequence of larger and larger running times.

The answer to your other questions are also yes, by the [time hierarchy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

On the one hand, every algorithm *(by which I will mean a Turing machine which halts on all inputs)* has computable runtime. On the other hand, by diagonalization for every computable function $f$ there is a computable set $X_f$ such that no Turing machine computing $X_f$ runs in time $O(f)$.

- This is a good exercise. The obvious approach doesn't work: the set of Turing machines which have runtime bounded by a given function is not computable. So you need a trick ...

So the only bound on runtime is the trivial one, that runtime has to be computable.

*(If we drop the requirement that our machines halt on all inputs, things get more complicated - see the [Busy Beaver function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_Beaver_game).)*